# Can we get rid of the grid background?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, se2.0, user-interface

Sorry, but all it does is make everything harder to read.

Answer (score 6):

And while we are at it, maybe the way accepted answers are marked could be made more prominent.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it's possible before the beta phase ends.

Comment: @All: Hey, i love the grid background. Please don't remove. One of the main reasons why i am an ardent visitor to this website only because of the beta website design.